# Is it advisable to use dagger 2 in a library

Tags: android, android-library, dagger-2

I would be creating a library (.aar) at my current workplace. It has a lot of complicated business processes and would definitely need a lot of automated tests, due to which I was planning on using dagger in my library.

But as it is a library, it needs to be as small as possible and depend on as fewer dependencies as possible. Not to mention that dagger just bloats anything it is used with.

So, I am in crossroads and unable to decide what should be my approach.

Can someone please help me come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

there isnt any problem with using dagger in a library if you use the dagger just inside. i mean as long as you dont expect the user of that to provide some dependencies for you from out of the library.

dagger makes the code complicated but not for yourself. assume the person who uses the library knows nothing about DI or dagger.

I myself have some project including a library using a dagger and even needing some dependencies to be provided from out of the library but since the whole project is mine and im not gonna export the library everything is ok.

so this depends how you gonna use it and i suggest if you wanna give this library to others dont expect them to implement dagger and provide some dependencies for you.

Comment: If my library module needs a **Context** reference (i.e. for file access on external storage), what should I do?

Comment: you can make it an android library if its not a problem for u or if thats a pure java library you can make a helper interface put in in your library and implement it in your app module and do whatever needs a context (or any other platform dependent object) in the implementation and send helper implementation as a dependency to your library.